# Опции команды в терминале

Tags: gcc, ос, терминал

У многих терминальных программ вроде известного GCC есть опции команд. У GCC это, например, -w, но есть и другие. Каким образом исполняемые файлы считывают эти опции? Просто как строку, а потом парсят? Или у командной оболочки есть API для считывания опций вида -option?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Всё очень просто, вначале командная оболочка берёт текст, введённый пользователем, и прогоняет через свой парсер, например, для `glob()` или де-экранирования символов. Разбивает на токены (по пробелам, учитывая окавыченные) и выполняет системный вызов `exec[lv][p[e]]()` перед этим выполнив `fork()`. Соответственно одним из параметров `exec[lv][p[e]]()` передаётся массив `char *argv[]` и его длина `int argc`. Внутри вызванной команды этот массив парсится либо с помощью стандартных библиотечных вызовов типа `getopt()`, `getopt_long()`, либо самостоятельно, либо в смешанном варианте.

На все приведенные выше вызовы есть станицы помощи `man` в секциях 2 и 3 для системных вызовов и библиотечных функций соответственно.

Для любопытных, почему параметры функции `main()` в языке Си принято называть `argv` и `argc`, и как запомнить их типы. Достаточно очевидно, что имена — английские аббревиатуры, а именно: `argv` — **ARG**ument **V**alues  (таким образом массив указателей на строки или `char *[]`) и `argc` — **ARG**umnet **C**ount (число аргументов, соответственно целое или `int`).

Comment: Спасибо! То есть в языке программы должна быть функцию вроде getopt()? А какие страницы man вы смотрели? glob и fork?

Comment: Не в языке, а в **тексте** программы должен быть парсер этих либо с использованием библиотечных функций, либо без. Странички руководства в своё время все упомянутые смотрел, деталей не помню. Ответ писался из головы.